# Shrinkwrap doing crazy things on surface topology

Tags: shrinkwrap

When I shrinkwrap the edge vertices of the inner element onto the inside surface of the frame(surrounding surface), the whole object (whose specific vertex group is being shrinkwrapped) just goes crazy...

what could be causing this?

Normals are ok, all transformations are set back to 0, no duplicated vertices... I think everything is ok, and I still don't know what is happening... ANY IDEAS??? I neep help!

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

You can try to:

- Raise the polygon count in both objects with subd modifier;
- Recheck there is no vertex incorrectly assigned to the vertex group;
- Lower the vertex weight;
- Small nudges to the objects to find a "sweet spot".

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I tried them all, but what worked in the end was adding another couple of edge loops really close to the shrinkwapped vertices. CHEERS!